# Can't figure out how to configure jquery file tree

Tags: jquery, css, file, tree, filetree

I just saw a file tree on http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/, and I don't know to configure it. I want to add the items and subitems manually but I don't get how to do this.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

#### NOTE:

Do you know that you don't need to add items manually? If so, read this section. If you really do want to add items manually, continue to the next section. The library takes care of that for you with a 'connector'. When you download the library, you'll have a subfolder with connectors in various languages. I'm running an IIS server so I use the `jqueryFileTree.aspx`  connector. In my JavaScript I run the following code to add a filetree to the element `#filetree`:

```
$('#filetree').fileTree({
    root: '/',
    script: '/jqueryFileTree.aspx'
}, function(filename) {
    alert('You selected ' + filename);
});
```

So adding items is really just a matter of adding files or directories to the path referenced by the `root` parameter.

#### Adding Items Manually

If you really want to add items manually, you'll need to first look at the structure of the underlying DOM element. Here's an example:

```
<div id="filetree" class="">
<ul class="jqueryFileTree" style="">
    <li class="directory expanded">
        <a href="#" rel="/sub/">sub</a>
        <ul class="jqueryFileTree" style="">
            <li class="file ext_txt">
                <a href="#" rel="/sub/file3.txt">file3.txt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="file ext_txt"><a href="#" rel="/file1.txt">file1.txt</a></li>
    <li class="file ext_txt"><a href="#" rel="/file2.txt">file2.txt</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can see in this example, the FileTree was added to the `<div id="#filetree"/>`. The root folder is represented by the first `<ul/>`, and each item in that folder is represented by a `<li/>` with a class of either `'file'` or `'directory'`. Within the directory in this example, another `<ul/>` with the same format is nested under the 'sub' `<li/>` to represent the 'sub' folder's contents. It is a recursive structure that could continue on indefinitely.

Adding items manually would be as simple as using jQuery.append() or jQuery.appendTo() to add a new `<li/>` with the correct attributes. You'll just need to select the correct element that will be the target of your added item.

An example of a file would be:

```
var liFile = $('<li/>',{
    'class' = 'file ext_txt'
}).append(
    $('<a/>',{
        'href' = '#',
        'rel'  = '/file4.txt'
    }).append(
        'file4.txt'
    )
);
```

That creates the following HTML: `<li class="file ext_txt"><a href="#" rel="/file4.txt">file4.txt</a></li>`.

Now just select the correct element to add it to. If you're just adding it to the root, this should be easy, just do the following:

```
$('#filetree ul').append(liFile);
```

You might also take a look at the source code for the FileTree library. It is only about 60 lines of code (if you exclude the comments).

Comment: Oh, I put the wrong question, I wanted to mean that I want to work on local server so I just want to put an <ul> in HTML where to be the folder tree and to be expandable and to look like the one I showed you.I just want the mechanism of the expand and collapse and some links in the list.Thank you.

Comment: Should work fine locally. What type of server are you running locally? You should still be able to use the filetree library if you can host the connector and make a request to it from jQuery. Although if you're just looking for the expandable hierarchy mechanism, just open the source code; it's really basic. Or you can try [jQuery TreeView](http://www.webappers.com/2008/10/07/treeview-expandable-and-collapsible-tree-jquery-plugin/) for another good expandable tree implementation.

Comment: Great! Feel free to post an answer for future visitors.